# I want to make a pie chart in Spring Boot connected with SQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, model-view-controller, repository, pie-chart

I use MVC Pattern with Controller, Repository, Entity and Service.
How can I make a Pie chart of status percentage for Orders (with status Tagname and status Count)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scP1Y.png)
I'm thinking about using Query, but it's not work:

```
@Query(
    value="select status,count(id) as statusCount from orders group by status",
    nativeQuery=true
)
public Map<String, Integer> reportByStatus();
```

I'm confused about Controller and Service parts. Can you help me? Thanks